# Copy VHD from azure disk to azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have an Azure disk of Windows 10 system. I want this disk must be converted into VHD and should be available in the azure storage account.

In easier words, I want my Azure VM data disk to be present in the azure storage BLOB without downloading the VHD onto my base machine. Is it possible. If yes, please guide me.

Can anyone please help me in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can copy the managed disk into the VHD file and store it in the storage. Here is the example code through PowerShell:

```
#Provide the subscription Id of the subscription where managed disk is created
$subscriptionId = "yourSubscriptionId"

#Provide the name of your resource group where managed is created
$resourceGroupName ="yourResourceGroupName"

#Provide the managed disk name 
$diskName = "yourDiskName"

#Provide Shared Access Signature (SAS) expiry duration in seconds e.g. 3600.
#Know more about SAS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Az.Storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1
$sasExpiryDuration = "3600"

#Provide storage account name where you want to copy the underlying VHD of the managed disk. 
$storageAccountName = "yourstorageaccountName"

#Name of the storage container where the downloaded VHD will be stored
$storageContainerName = "yourstoragecontainername"

#Provide the key of the storage account where you want to copy the VHD of the managed disk. 
$storageAccountKey = 'yourStorageAccountKey'

#Provide the name of the destination VHD file to which the VHD of the managed disk will be copied.
$destinationVHDFileName = "yourvhdfilename"

#Set the value to 1 to use AzCopy tool to download the data. This is the recommended option for faster copy.
#Download AzCopy v10 from the link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10
#Ensure that AzCopy is downloaded in the same folder as this file
#If you set the value to 0 then Start-AzStorageBlobCopy will be used. Azure storage will asynchronously copy the data. 
$useAzCopy = 1 

# Set the context to the subscription Id where managed disk is created
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

#Generate the SAS for the managed disk 
$sas = Grant-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName -DurationInSecond $sasExpiryDuration -Access Read 

#Create the context of the storage account where the underlying VHD of the managed disk will be copied
$destinationContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

#Copy the VHD of the managed disk to the storage account
if($useAzCopy -eq 1)
{
    $containerSASURI = New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Context $destinationContext -ExpiryTime(get-date).AddSeconds($sasExpiryDuration) -FullUri -Name $storageContainerName -Permission rw
    $containername,$sastokenkey = $containerSASURI -split "\?"
    $containerSASURI = "$containername/$destinationVHDFileName`?$sastokenkey"
    azcopy copy $sas.AccessSAS $containerSASURI

}else{

    Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $storageContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -DestBlob $destinationVHDFileName
}
```

But in my test, there is something wrong with the VHD file when you use the `azcopy` command. And the command `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy` works well. So I recommend command `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy` for you. And for more details, see [Export/Copy the VHD of a managed disk to a storage account in different region with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-copy-managed-disks-vhd).

Comment: @AnilSharma What about the check? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it as the answer.